# Call Python script with filename argument when using bash script

Tags: python, shell, input, command-line, argparse

I am trying to run my Python script (`csv_builder.py`) via a Bash Shell script (`csv`) that calls my Python script. In the script, I request an input for a filename.

The bash script is below:

```
chmod +x D:/Users/michaeld/Python/csv_builder/csv_builder.py
python3 D:/Users/michaeld/Python/csv_builder/csv_builder.py
```

The beginning of my Python script that calls for the input is below:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description = 'This inputs the .csv file')
parser.add_argument('--i', required = True, type = str, help = '.csv filename')
args = parser.parse_args()
csv_name = args.i
# csv_name = input('\nEnter the .csv file name: \n') This was the original input
```

I have been trying to run on command line as, but I get error: `the following arguments are required: --i`:

```
csv --i file_name.csv
```

I would like to be able to define that filename input in the command line when running the Bash Shell script (`csv`). Is there a better way to do this? If I can just type `csv file_name.csv`, that would be ideal.

Comment: Why don't you just call `python3 ...csv_builder.py --i file_name.csv` from the command line? Or add `--i file_name.csv` to the second line in the shell script?

Comment: BTW making the Python script executable is unnecessary when you invoke it with `python3 ...csv_builder.py` explicitly

Comment: I am trying to make the script usable for many different types of .csv file names. Also, trying to not have to type that whole line every time, I would like to only have to call the bash script name. As for the executable... when is it necessary then? I could only get the script to work when I called out the whole path.

Comment: When I run python3 csv_builder.py --i file_name.csv in the same folder it works but when I try to use my bash script that is in my bin folder, it is giving me the error. How can I fix my bash script to work with argparse?

Comment: When you define an argument with a '-i' flag, you have to use that in the commandline (or script call).  The file name is not enough.  But you could create a `positional` argument instead.  The argparse docs should be clear enough about that.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce the problem:

```
$ ./csv --i file_name.csv

$ ./csv --i 
usage: csv [-h] [--i I]
csv: error: argument --i: expected one argument
```

Try run your file with `./csv`, so you are sure that you are executing the right file.

Comment: I realized I had the argument "required = True" for my argument. The error I get is csv.py: error: the following arguments are required: --i. Why is it not seeing my file name argument?

Answer (score 0):

```py
# csv.py
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='This inputs the .csv file')
parser.add_argument('filename', type=str, help='.csv filename')

args = parser.parse_args()
print(args.filename)
```

Run with `python csv.py file_name.csv`